# Pointer to string not incrementing (C programming)

Tags: c

I have two string shown below:

```
char code  *text_to_compare = "TesT";     
char code  *dictionary = "TesTT,Tes,Tes,TesT.";
```

In a part of the program I used the following code where it increments the pointers for both strings to point to the next characters.

```
ch_A = text_to_compare[i++]; 
ch_B = dictionary[j++];
```

Why is pointer j being incremented but pointer i is remaining as it was?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Below is the full code. The aim of this project is to compare a string with a list of words. Integer i is not incrementing only after the program enters the else statement.

```
#include <string.h>

char code *text_to_compare = "TesT";
char code *dictionary = "TesTT,Tes,Tes,TesT.";

int bring_characters(char pdata *, char pdata *, char ch_A, char ch_B, char i,
                     char j);

void main(void) {
    unsigned char ch_A;
    unsigned char ch_B;
    unsigned char i = 0;
    unsigned char j = 0;

    char pdata N1;
    char pdata N2;
    int result;

    ch_A = text_to_compare[i]; // take a caharacter from the text
    ch_B = dictionary[j];

    result = bring_characters(&N1, &N2, ch_A, ch_B, i, j);

    if (result == 0) {
        while (1)
            ;
    }

    else {
        while (1)
            ;
    }

    while (1)
        ;
}

int bring_characters(char pdata *N1, char pdata *N2, char ch_A, char ch_B,
                     char i, char j) {
    do {

        if (ch_A == ch_B) {
            ch_A = text_to_compare[i++]; // take a caharacter from the text
            ch_B = dictionary[j++];

            if ((ch_A == '\0') && ((ch_B == ',') || (ch_B == '.'))) {
                while (1)
                    ; // load idata-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            }
        }

        else {
            i = 0; // refresh pointer

            ch_A = text_to_compare[i]; // take a caharacter from the text
            ch_B = dictionary[j++];
        }
    } while (ch_B != '.');

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: you code does not increment pointer, it increments interger variables

Comment: Also, what's "code", how are "ch_A" and "ch_B" defined? Show us some running code.

Comment: In the `else` case, you're not incrementing `i` at all.

Comment: Your question does not have sufficient detail in order to identify issue(s). You have 2 char pointers pointing to strings. You are iterating through the strings using indices "i" and "j" which are being incremented. If you are comparing the 2 strings ... how ? Are you comparing beyond text_to_compare[3] etc. etc. ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whew, there's a lot going on here! Now that you've added the full code it looks like in your attempt to move on to the next word you have prevented yourself from moving on.. you'll need to do some major revisions to get this guy working.

The first thing you need to do is figure out how you would do this on paper, then step by step try to reproduce that in your code.

Here's a function to kickstart you:

```
int find_next_match(char toFind, int startingPosition, char* mainString){

    int counter = startingPosition;

    char buf = mainString[counter];

    while(buf != NULL){
        if (buf == toFind){
            return counter;
        }

        counter++;

        buf = mainString[counter];
    }
    return -1; //error
}
```

You can use something like this to find the next instance of the first character in your string, then you can implement a loop to determine if that is a match.

Good luck, you can do it!